# Is it possible to export the cubes from remote SSAS server to local?

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

I'm working on a BI report where I have created a cube on the client machine.
Now I wanted to work on the SSRS to create reports.Is is possible to export and then import the cube data into local machine and use a data source for SSRS?

I'm using Visual Studio version 2010.

Comment: Assuming you have SSAS on your local machine, you can take a backup of the SSAS database and restore it to your local machine. I'm not sure what this gains you other than you don't have to have connectivity to the remote machine while building the report.

Comment: ok. Actually, the idea it make others work on the reports while I continue to work on creating other cubes. So is there anything we have to change while restoring to local. Also , can you please let me know how to take a backup of SSAS database?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the live database in Visual Studio, save it as a project on your hard drive, change the project to deploy to your local SSAS Server, and deploy it.